# How to check for installed web app (PWA) updates when using precache method

Tags: progressive-web-apps, service-worker, service-worker-events

I have a Progressive Web App in which the service worker is configured as shown below. I follow precache method. Every files will be cached first and the requests will be served from the cache. If there is no match in local cache, then request is served over network. If everything fails an offline/error page is shown. Everything works fine. But I am stuck at giving an update to the index.html file.

```js
const pb_cache = "cv1";
const assets = [
    "./manifest.json",
    "./index.html",
    "./offline.html",
]

self.addEventListener("install", installEvent => {
  installEvent.waitUntil(
    caches.open(pb_cache)
    .then((cache) => {
      return cache.addAll(assets)
      .then(() => {
        return self.skipWaiting(); //To forces the waiting service worker to become the active service worker
      })
    })
  );
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
  event.respondWith(
    caches.match(event.request).then(function(response) {
      if (response) {
        return response;
      }
      return fetch(event.request).then(function(response) {
        if (response.status === 404) {
          return caches.match('/offline.html');
        }
        return response
      });
    }).catch(function() {
      return caches.match('/offline.html');
    })
  );
});
```

**Scenario**
I have installed the web app to my android phone. Everything is cached and works fine. I need to make changes to the index.html file. So i have added a few tweaks to the file and updated the website. But since the web app installed in android serves local cache, the change in website is not reflected. So I need a mechanism to check for update. What parameter or what thing should I check for update ? I have read many documents related to this and I am not able to grasp the content.

One thing I know is that I have to check for update somewhere in service worker and add it to cache when found in network. I don't know which event or what criteria to check for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "manual" way to do this would be to include something like

```
// VERSION: 1
```

at the top of your service worker file, and remember to change that number whenever you make *any* change to an asset that you're caching during `install`. The updated version number will result in the automatic [service worker update check](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/lifecycle#updates) indicating that there's something new, which will in turn trigger the `install` handler in your updated service worker file to fire again. All of your precached assets will be added to the cache again at this point.

After some clarification in the comments, I believe that using `cache.addAll()` inside of your `install` handler might be problematic, because you don't have control over your `Cache-Control` headers, and `cache.addAll()` will go to the HTTP cache before going to the network. Here's an alternative `install` handler that will work around this problem by passing in `Request` objects with the appropriate `cache` property, instead of passing in URL strings:

```
self.addEventListener("install", installEvent => {
  const cacheBypassRequests = assets.map(
    (url) => new Request(url, {cache: 'reload'});

  installEvent.waitUntil(
    caches.open(pb_cache)
    .then((cache) => {
      return cache.addAll(cacheBypassRequests)
      .then(() => {
        return self.skipWaiting();
      })
    })
  );
});
```

This is obviously error-prone, as you might forget to bump that value when you make a small tweak to one of your assets.

A somewhat more robust way of doing this is to add a step to a build process for your web app that will update your service worker file's version number each time you redeploy.

A more production-ready approach is to use a tool that's geared towards solving this specific use case, like [`workbox-precaching`](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-precaching) along with the node, webpack, or CLI build interfaces. That will take care of automatically generating a hash of each asset that you want to precache, triggering a new installation whenever one of them changes, and only re-downloading the updated assets.

Comment: Ok. If I use the first method, which is error-prone, does clearing the previous cache before updating the current one solves caching issues ?

Comment: `cache.addAll()` will overwrite previous entries with whatever is retrieved from the network, so you don't have to explicitly clear anything out first. But you do need to remember to update the manual version string, and you need to make sure that your HTTP Cache-Control headers don't result in you retrieving the previously cached response, i.e. make sure that your caching headers allow you to go directly to the network.

Comment: I am not that much expert in HTTP cache-control headers. I am hosting this code in github. So could you please explain this ?

Comment: Also which is better ? Adding `// VERSION: 1` or updating the cache name each time when changes are made ?

Comment: I'd update a VERSION value unless you're also cleaning up old cache names in an `activate` handler. You don't really have control over `Cache-Control:` headers in GitHub pages, unfortunately. The last I checked, GitHub pages would use the HTTP cache for 10 minutes, which could mean that your `cache.addAll()` call might end up hitting the HTTP cache instead of the network.

Comment: So using a VERSION value fix the caching issue mentioned above comment ?

Comment: No, it wouldn't bypass the HTTP cache. I can adjust my original answer to show an alternative to `cache.addAll()` that will bypass the HTTP cache, though.

Comment: That would be much helpful. I am really stuck for 2 days. I have searched a lot and is having difficulty in grasping these things.

Comment: I have one more question. Should i ask it as a new question or ask it here in comments ?

Comment: New question, please :-)

Comment: This answer works. Thanks a lot for the help. could you please take a look at this ? https://stackoverflow.com/q/66338795/8913606

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution for this implementation is to update the `pb_cache` value any time you change your `index.html`, that will cause the service worker to be updated and `index.html` to be re-cached. But, the old cached version won't be removed.

Here's a solution using [Workbox](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/), it will pre-cache the files indicated in `urls`, then when a request for one of those files is made, it will use a [stale, while revalidate](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-strategies#stale-while-revalidate) strategy. The user may see an old version initially, but on the next reload, they'll get the latest. For any other requests (that are not in `urls`, it will use a [network only](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-strategies#network_only) strategy. And finally, [`setCatchHandler`](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-routing#set_a_catch_handler) will return the offline page if it's unable to get the page from the network.

```js
importScripts('https://storage.googleapis.com/workbox-cdn/releases/6.1.0/workbox-sw.js');

// URLs to cache and keep up to date
const urls = [
  '/index.html',
  '/manifest.json',
  '/script.js',
  '/style.css',
  '/offline.html',
];

// Turn on logging for development, change to false for production
workbox.setConfig({
  debug: true
});

const {clientsClaim} = workbox.core;
const {NetworkOnly} = workbox.strategies;
const {StaleWhileRevalidate} = workbox.strategies;
const {warmStrategyCache} = workbox.recipes;
const {registerRoute} = workbox.routing;
const {setDefaultHandler} = workbox.routing;
const {setCatchHandler} = workbox.routing;

self.skipWaiting();
clientsClaim();

// Normalize cache key URLs to:
// - drop query parameters
// - for URLs ending in '/', append 'index.html'
async function cacheKeyWillBeUsed({request}) {
  const url = new URL(request.url);
  if (url.pathname.endsWith('/')) {
    return url.origin + url.pathname + 'index.html';
  }
  return url.origin + url.pathname;
}

// Initialize a stale while revalidate strategy.
// See https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-strategies#stale-while-revalidate
const strategy = new StaleWhileRevalidate({
  plugins:[
    {cacheKeyWillBeUsed},
  ],
});

// Ensure that an initial set of URLs are cached,
// so that the PWA works offline immediately.
warmStrategyCache({urls, strategy});

// Use the Stale While Revalidate strategy for URLs in `urls`
registerRoute(
  ({url}) => {
    let pathname = url.pathname;
    // Normalize paths, for URLs ending in '/', append 'index.html'
    if (pathname.endsWith('/')) {
      pathname += 'index.html';
    }
    return urls.includes(pathname);
  }, strategy
);

// Use only the network for all other requests
setDefaultHandler(new NetworkOnly());

// This "catch" handler is triggered when any of the other routes fail to
// generate a response. This is a simplified version of the Comprehensive Fallback
// https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/advanced-recipes#comprehensive_fallbacks
setCatchHandler(({event}) => {
  if (event.request.destination === 'document') {
    return caches.match('/offline.html');
  }
});
```

This whole solution combines a number of recipes from the [Advanced Recipes](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/advanced-recipes) section of Workbox.

Comment: Changing the cache name looks fit here. I will consider workbox options later. Is it better to overwrite the previous cache or delete and add as new cache ?

Comment: Delete and add a new cache is slightly better.

Comment: Ok. As the other person in other answer mentioned,  Adding // VERSION: 1 to worker file or updating the cache name each time when changes are made ? Which is better ?

Comment: Thanks for your help. Thanks a lot. I have got an approximate idea on how to make this :)