# New update available message and post action

Tags: progressive-web-apps, service-worker

I have this code which checks for changes in service worker

```
if ("serviceWorker" in navigator) {
    window.addEventListener("load", function() {
        navigator.serviceWorker.register(worker).then(function(reg) {
            reg.onupdatefound = function() {
                var installingWorker = reg.installing;

                installingWorker.onstatechange = function() {
                    switch (installingWorker.state) {
                        case 'installed':
                            if (navigator.serviceWorker.controller) {
                                console.log('New or updated content is available.');
                            } else {
                                console.log('Content is now available offline!');
                            }
                            break;
                    }
                };
            };
        }).catch(function(e) {
            console.error('Error during service worker registration:', e);
        });
    })
}
```

By referring many documents, I came to know that, the version will be updated only once the installed app is reopened again. Is there any javascript event to reload or reopen the installed app so that I can show a button to click when update is available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using a service worker that aggressively precaches versioned URLs, and serves only the versions of each URL that's associated with the actual service worker, then you'd need to tell the new, "[waiting](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/lifecycle#waiting)" service worker to "[skip waiting](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/lifecycle#skip_the_waiting_phase)" and activate before the new set of cached responses will go into effect. Once the new service worker skips waiting, you'd want to reload all open clients so that they get the new resources.

This requires coordination between the page's JavaScript as well as adding a `message` handler to your service worker. One [recipe](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/advanced-recipes#offer_a_page_reload_for_users) to handle this coordination can be found in the Workbox documentation. (You can use this even if you're not using Workbox for your precaching.)

Comment: So in the previous code you have given me, there is the code to update the cache without causing HTTP cache control issues. So implementing this functionality cause issue in that ?  Also which event like `installingWorker.onstatechange` can be used to write function to tell the new worker to skip waiting ?